# Store an array within a 2d array Java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, multidimensional-array

So why doesn't this work? Not really sure why this isn't possible- I just want to store an array of size 2 inside a 2d array.

I know this would be equivalent to setting storage[0][0] = array[0] and storage[0][1] = array[1], but just wondering why this is incorrect.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[][] storage = new boolean[10][2];
        boolean[] array = new boolean[2];
        array[0] = true;
        array[1] = false;

        storage[0][] = array; //Why can't I do this?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be `storage[0]=  array;`, because if storage is a 2-dim array `storage[i]` is a 1-dim array, like your `array` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a stray pair of brackets in your assignment. Just use

```
storage[0] = array;
```

Comment: @FraserPrice I note that you haven't accepted answers on any of the questions you've asked. If an answer is helpful, please upvote, and if one solves your problem, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `boolean[][] storage = new boolean[10][2]` declares an array and initialise it.

So, you have created 11 arrays. One of `boolean[]` element type and 10 of `boolean type`.

It's good, If you want to access it's members directly, but if you create an inner array lately with `new boolean[]`, it's an overhead.

Use `boolean[][] storage = new boolean[10][];` instead.

Then, you can access it's elements, which are `boolean[]` type, and assign your array to it.

```
storage[0] = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the stray square brackets(as I'm sure you know). Your code should look like this:

```
storage[0] = array;
```

The previous answers did not really explain why though, so that's what I'll do.

What your trying to do is make the first position(`storage[0]`) hold the same value as `array`. `array` is 1 dimensional, so it can only be *part* of `storage`, which is 2 dimensional.